# "Request sample documents for which to follow" vs. "from which to follow"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am editing a document that has the following sentence:

> If there are no brand standards published regarding logo use and colors, the team will request sample documents for which to follow.

The "for which to follow" seems so awkward  to me. Should it be "from which to follow" or should I just rewrite the whole sentence?

Comment: That is such a strange construction that it is risky to guess at the meaning. Perhaps it means sample documents "to go by".

Answer (score 1):

I would simply delete the two words *for which*. That gives you:

> If there are no brand standards published regarding logo use and colors, the team will request sample documents to follow.

As MετάEd suggests, it means "to go by" or "to imitate" or "{that/which} we can follow". That's all that's necessary, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The construction "*noun preposition* which to *verb*" needs to have the appropriate preposition, which can be tested by forming a simple phrase using the components, as in

> We will follow for the sample documents.

or

> We will follow from the sample documents.

Although the latter might be a slight improvement, neither of these work well.  One could change the verb to a more appropriate one, as in

> We will work from the sample documents.
>
> ... sample documents from which to work.

or one could drop the preposition entirely since *follow* doesn't need one:

> ... sample documents to follow.

Comment: I like your last suggestion best: _the team will request sample documents to follow._ Just dele the _for which_.